# sublime text 2 - multiple key bindings don't work, only last one

Tags: sublime-text-2

I set up a few custom key bindings, but only the last one always works, the ones before it don't.

```
[
{ 
    // "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "<b>${0:$SELECTION}</b>"}
    "keys": ["ctrl+i"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "<i>${0:$SELECTION}</i>"},
    "keys": ["f11"], "command": "clone_file"

    // "keys": ["ctrl+alt+t"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "ṭ"}
    // "keys": ["ctrl+alt+n"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "ṇ"}
}
]
```

So now `ctrl+i` does not work, but if I comment out the `f11 clone file`, then it works. It's the same for each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime keybindings are stored as JSON.
JSON objects are declared with `{` and `}`, while JSON arrays are written with `[` and `]`. Key-value pairs as well as objects are separated with `,`.

So you did overwrite "keys" and "command" for one single command every time. Your keybindings would have to look like that:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "<b>${0:$SELECTION}</b>"} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+i"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "<i>${0:$SELECTION}</i>"} },
    { "keys": ["f11"], "command": "clone_file" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+t"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "ṭ"} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+n"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "ṇ"} }
]
```

Comment: damn, finally I resolved this :D. Thank you so much.

Comment: Happy to help. Although it was asked a while ago, I just wanted to answer this unanswered question :D